# Clicking on a List Item in html

Tags: html, css, listitem

I'm trying to click a list item to activate a hyperlink,

Currently I have a list of hyperlinks but I would like the user to be able to click on the list item to navigate instead of the text displayed.

```
<ul>
<li>
<a Class=MenuLink href="Index.php">Index</a>
 </li>
<li>
</ul>
```

is it possible to make the list item clickable? or is it possible to make the background of the list item change when the hyperlink is hovered over?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NWS6J/

Set the `.MenuLink` elements to `display: block`:

```
.MenuLink {
    display: block
}
```

They will then cover the entire area of the `li`. You can change the `background-color` of the elements on `:hover`:

```
.MenuLink:hover {
    background: red
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to use the class, such as 'ul a.Menulink`?

Comment: Another suggestion I would probably make would be to class the UL if all or most A's were to be block, that way there's less markup and subclassing is simpler. I'm not saying you add that, that's just my additional 2 cents.

Comment: I decided to use 

#Menu ul li a { ... } and #Menu ul li a:hover { ... } that got it looking how I want it, only problem is the text color is now the same color as the border. Thanks for the help I'll look into your suggestions as well.